# Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api

Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

> response: {"error":{"message":"\u05d0\u05d9\u05df
>   \u05d0\u05e4\u05e9\u05e8\u05d5\u05ea \u05dc\u05d8\u05e2\u05d5\u05df
>   \u05d0\u05ea (truncated...)

install socialite package in laravel

```
public function Callback(Request $request, $provider)
{
     try {
        $userSocial = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    } 

    catch (Exception $e) {

        return redirect ('/');
    }
    if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    //$userSocial =   Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    $users       =   User::where(['email' => $userSocial->getEmail()])->first();
    if($users){
        Auth::login($users);
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name'          => $userSocial->getName(),
            'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
            'image'         => $userSocial->getAvatar(),
            'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
            'provider'      => $provider,
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('/home');
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please, be more clear in your question.

Comment: I change config/services.php about facebook.redirect from http to https, after that use the command: php artisan config:clear I take a lot of time to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php sdk (https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) .It supports from php version 5.4.